# I'm getting following error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then') at lazyInitializer at resolveLazy " while using React Lazy

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-functional-component, react-lazy-load

[This is the Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfck7.png)

//This is my code where I used the react lazy in React functional component.

```
import React,{Suspense, lazy} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Loader from "./components/loader"
const AboutLazy = lazy(()=>{import("./pages/aboutus")})
 <BrowserRouter>
      <HomeContext.Provider value={{ homes}}>    
            <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>     
            <Routes>
            <Route path="/aboutus" element={<AboutLazy />} /> 
            </Routes>
           </ Suspense > 
           </>
      </HomeContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </>
```

I'm expecting to lazy load the webPage using react lazy

Comment: can you remove the `{}` from your lazy import statement. It should look like this - `lazy(()=> import("./pages/aboutus"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your import command

```
const AboutLazy = lazy(()=>{import("./pages/aboutus")})
```

to remove the `{}` parenthesis since you are trying to import a component and not return anything

replace with this one:

```
lazy(()=> import("./pages/aboutus"))
```